# Show label when values in 3 select box is selected in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

What is the easiest way to preform operation that will check if values from 3 drop downs are selected, and if they are it will show label with some content, when using AngularJs.

I have this 3 drop downs:

```
<div class="col-md-2" ng-class="{ 'has-error has-feedback': addNewTestSession.sessionStartTime.$touched && addNewTestSession.sessionStartTime.$invalid }">
    <label for="sessionStartTime">Session Start Time<span class="mandatory">*</span></label>
    <select id="sessionStartTime" name="sessionStartTime" class="form-control" 
        ng-model="newTestSessionCtrl.formData.sessionTime"
        ng-options="time for time in newTestSessionCtrl.viewData.sessionStarTimeIntervals"
        ng-required="true">
        <option value="" disabled selected>Select</option>
    </select>
    <span ng-show="addNewTestSession.sessionStartTime.$touched && addNewTestSession.sessionStartTime.$invalid" 
        class="fa fa-warning form-control-feedback"
        uib-popover="This field is required." 
        popover-trigger="'mouseenter'"
        popover-placement="auto right"
        popover-class="additional-info"></span>             
</div>
<div class="col-md-1">
    <label for="timeZone">Time zone</label>
    <select id="timeZone" name="timeZone" class="form-control"
        ng-init="newTestSessionCtrl.formData.timeZone = newTestSessionCtrl.viewData.timeZones[15]" 
        ng-model="newTestSessionCtrl.formData.timeZone"
        ng-options="timeZone.name for timeZone in newTestSessionCtrl.viewData.timeZones track by timeZone.name">
    </select>
</div>
<div class="col-md-2" ng-class="{ 'has-error has-feedback': addNewTestSession.sessionCloseTime.$touched && addNewTestSession.sessionCloseTime.$invalid }">
    <label for="sessionCloseTime">Session to start within<span class="mandatory">*</span> 
        <i class="fa fa-question-circle" 
            uib-popover="Interviewee must start the Personal Test Session within this time-window counted from the session's start date & time." 
            popover-trigger="'mouseenter'"
            popover-placement="auto right"
            popover-class="additional-info"></i>
    </label>
    <select id="sessionCloseTime" name="sessionCloseTime" class="form-control" 
        ng-model="newTestSessionCtrl.formData.sessionCloseInterval"
        ng-options="time.name for time in newTestSessionCtrl.viewData.sessionCloseIntervals"
        ng-required="true">
        <option value="" disabled selected>Select</option>
        </select>
</div>
```

I want to check when when all of them has selected value and let say to show label that says just "Hello" next to them.

What is the best way to preform this in AngularJs?

Answer (score 0):

One way is to explicitly check that it is selected.

```
<span ng-show="newTestSessionCtrl.formData.sessionTime && newTestSessionCtrl.formData.timeZone && newTestSessionCtrl.formData.sessionCloseInterval">Hello</span>
```

If you are certain that these 3 select option are the only input in the form and the only validation is `ng-required`, you can have:

```
<form name="formName">
    <span ng-show="!formName.$invalid">Hello</span>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a function in your scope/controller that return true/false like that:

```
newTestSessionCtrl.isAllSelected = function(){
  // rules
  return newTestSessionCtrl.formData.timeZone === 3 && newTestSessionCtrl.formData.sessionCloseInterval === 3 && newTestSessionCtrl.formData.sessionTime === 3;
}
```

Write your own rules inside function. It's just a sample.

In your html:

```
<label ng-show="newTestSessionCtrl.isAllSelected()"> all selected!</label>
```